# How do I create the neo4j manual as an epub?

Tags: neo4j

I'd like to read the neo4j manual (especially for cypher) as an epub on my e-reader. How can I create that documenation? Given that the documentation is written in asciidoc, it should be possible.

Trying to create the epub directly with a2x (8.6.8):

```
cd manuals/src
a2x -fepub -dbook neo4j-manual.asciidoc
```

results in:

```
a2x: ERROR: "xmllint" --nonet --noout --valid "/home/joerg/projects/neo4j/tmp/neo4j/manual/src/neo4j-manual.xml" returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Even just creating the documentation (after building neo4j) fails for me:

```
git clone git@github.com:neo4j/neo4j.git
cd neo4j/manual
mvn clean install
```

gives me:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.neo4j.build.plugins:license-maven-plugin:3:check (check-licenses) on project neo4j-manual: Some files do not have the expected license header ->
```

So, any ideas how I could create the epub?

**Solution**

nawroth pointed out the solution. Here is what I did in the end:

```
apt-get install dbtoepub
git clone https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j.git
cd neo4j
mvn clean install -DdocsBuild -Ddebug -Dlicense.skip=true -Dlicensing.skip
cd manual/cd target/
ln -s src/images .
dbtoepub neo4j-manual-shortinfo.xml
```

I've included the created neo4j.epub file on https://baach.de/Members/jhb/neo4j-manual-as-epub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try this build on the full repo:

mvn clean install -DdocsBuild -Ddebug -Dlicense.skip=true -Dlicensing.skip

-DdocsBuild will ensure that all modules produce the special *-docs.jar.
-Ddebug will make the build of the manual keep the docbook files around.

This should give you a docbook file in:
*neo4j/manual/target/neo4j-manual-shortinfo.xml*
which is the one the PDF is built from.
Note that there's a few more files there which get included during the transformation, so xinclude has to be enbled when processing the file.

I haven't looked into publishing to epub yet, but the above should at least give you a valid docbook file to play with!

Comment: That worked great! Thanks a lot. Will update my question to include the solution.

Comment: There's been quite an amount of docs fixes the last days, you might want to build yourself a new manual. Here's the additional customization layer we apply on the docbook when rendering the PDF: https://github.com/neo4j/doctools/blob/master/src/main/resources/conf/fo.xsl

Specifically, it removes some elements intended for html only:
<xsl:template match="formalpara[@role = 'cypherconsole']" />
<xsl:template match="simpara[@role = 'cypherconsole']" />

Maybe I can make them go away in a different step, will have to look into that.